# Mono continue if not present

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Given two sessions (A & B) as strings, my goal is to check if A is valid in the database. If A exists, return it. If A is not provided (or does not exist in the database), I would like to proceed with checking session B in the database.

The problem with my code below is that I return regardless whether A has been found or not. Instead, I would like to check that if A is not found (is empty), proceed with checking B.  Is there a way to check if a Mono does **not** exist?

```
String sessionA = "1";
String sessionB = "2";


public Mono<Session> getSession() {
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(sessionA)) {
        return myDatabaseService.findByKeyOne(sessionA); // Should only return if it exists, otherwise, check session B
    }

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(sessionB)) {
        return myDatabaseService.findByAnotherSession(sessionB);
    }

    throw new Exception(); // If both sessions have not been found
}


// My Database Service (dummy code)
public Mono<Session> findByKeyOne(String session) {
    try {
        return myDatabase.find(); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        return Mono.empty() // If an error occurrd or no result has been found, return empty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on @Eugene Botyanovsky's answer with addressing the optional sessionA, you may try something like this:

```java
// Return an exception in case both sessionA and sessionB are empty.
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(sessionA) && StringUtils.isEmpty(sessionB)) {
  return Mono.error(new Exception());
}

// simply return an empty Mono if sessionA is empty.
Mono<Session> sessionAMono = StringUtils.isEmpty(sessionA) 
                            ? Mono.empty() 
                            : myDatabaseService.findByKeyOne(sessionA);

return sessionAMono
         .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> myDatabaseService.findByAnotherSession(sessionB)));
```

In this case, both scenarios when sessionA is empty, as well as when `myDatabaseService.findByKeyOne(sessionA)` returns an empty result (assuming that it does).

Edit:
Unrelated to your concern but I wanted to point out in your `findByKeyOne` function, since the `myDatabase.find()` is returning a Mono, wrapping it with try catch won't work since it's asynchronous. Which means you'll need to handle any potential error in the same stream. You can do something like:

```java
return myDatabase.find()
            .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.empty();
```

Comment: This is almost perfect - would it be possible to check if that neither SessionA or SessionB exist, an exception would be thrown? (I have edited my original post with the exception). This is I think the only scenario that still needs to be covered. Sorry for not mentioning that earlier - I had forgot to add this exception in my original post.

Comment: @Katie, I updated the answer to include the condition to return an error in case both sessionA and sessionB are non-existent.

Comment: Nice one! 
The strange thing is, when I run my code now using the debugger, I see that sessionAMono contains the data properly, but the switchIfEmpty (last line) still thinks sessionAMono is empty and the findByAnotherSession is being conducted. Shouldn't it return without executing this database call?

Comment: I have actually wrapped the last line using Mono.defer to make it work:
return Mono.defer(() -> sessionAMono.switchIfEmpty(myDatabaseService.findByAnotherSession(sessionB));) 
Not sure why this works fine if I use defer. Do you think it is good?

Comment: nevermind, now if SessionA and SessionB are both present, both requests to the database are made (instead of only SessionA)

Comment: @katie, yes good catch. Sorry, I also missed the fact that passing `myDatabaseService.findByAnotherSession(sessionB)` inside switchIfEmpty will get evaluated immediately instead of it being lazy. You almost got it, we need to use `Mono.defer` in this case. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and for sticking to look into all the cases!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mono#switchIfEmpty](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#switchIfEmpty-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-)

This is as simple as:

```
myDatabaseService.findByKeyOne(sessionA)
    .switchIfEmpty(myDatabaseService.findByAnotherSession(sessionB))
```

Now you only have to check your nullabilities

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Eugene. The problem with this is that I want to check sessionB, if sessionA is not provided initially too. In other words, with this solution, I would have a duplicate IF check for SessionB. Is it possible to simply keep the second if statement and "continue" with the flow if sessionA has not been found? Ideally something that is switchIfNotEmpty (of course this does not exist though)